# Microsoft-adal -angular6 working only after refresh in angular 6

Tags: angular, azure, access-token, adal, microsoft-adal-angular6

I am using microsoft-adal-angular6 for azure ad authentication in my angular 6 app. Currently when the app loads for the first time, it calls the api methods 2 times and i see my loading icon. But after i refresh the page, it works fine.

1. Why is it working this way? what can be done to avoid this. I have already tried changing redirecturi to  **/redirect.html**, but no luck.
2. The same thing happens when i navigate from my main site to sub-site . After i navigate to sub-site, ill have to refresh to page to get the token working .

Thanks for your time and reply in advance. Any sample code in angular 2 or above would be very helpful.

Comment: `Any sample code in angular 2 or above would be very helpful` well I was gonig to say the same. Could you provide some code ? Some [mcve] ?

Comment: Will be uploding the code , but in the menawhile i would giv u the gist. I have defined adalconfig in environment.ts and using that adalconfig in msAdalAngular6ConfigFactory of app.module.ts.  @Maryannah

Comment: I found why it isn't displaying on first load- it is because the iframe that gets the token, loads app in its window which is hidden. When i changed the visibility of iframe i could see the data over there. Still not clue how to stop this behaviour. @Maryannah

Answer (score 0):

This is because the azure authentication token expires every 1 hour. See my answer in the below link which may give you an idea.

[Adal.js Token refresh issue in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054526/adal-js-token-refresh-issue-in-angular/60113130#60113130)